# JMeter not replacing reference variable from regular expression extractor

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to send a `POST` request to my login url from JMeter:

[image]

In order to do inject csrf token, I am using regular expression extractor, which looks like this:

[image]

I can confirm that regular expression is working:

[image]

However, `${token}` is not being replaced:

[image]

What could be wrong?

**P.S. How request is structured:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regular Expression extractor (as well as any other [Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)) follow [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so you need to place it **as a child** of the request which returns this value
2. [Using regular expressions to parse HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) (they are too fragile and sensitive to any markup change), I would recommend switching to [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) instead, the relevant configuration should be as simple as:

   - Reference Name: `token`
   - CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]`
   - Attribute: `value`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted an updated. I think I put extractor as a child. Can you please take a look

Comment: You misunderstand "correlation" concept. Your test should look as follows: 1. Open Login Page (GET request). 2 Extract CSRF token 3. Perform Login (POST request) providing credentials and the token.  See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) for more details.

Comment: It makes total sense now. Thank you.